# What is an exception handling personality function?

Tags: llvm

I've looked at the documentation for the LLVM EH intrinsics, and also the Itanium ABI, and I'm stumped on a few things.

What *is* an exception personality function? What jobs does it perform? How would I go about creating one?

Comment: The personality attribute permits functions to specify what function to use for exception handling. https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#personality-function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had exactly the same question. I've just found [these articles](https://monkeywritescode.blogspot.com/p/c-exceptions-under-hood.html) which thoroughly explains how it works, the full exception handling process, including the exact purpose of the personality function and a step-by-step implementation.

For the sake of having an answer on SO, here is a brief summary of the personality behavior when an exception occurs (but you really should look at the <strike>18</strike> 22 articles that this guy wrote about this !):

- First, it will be called once for each stack frame (lookup phase), and has to return a value (from an enumeration) telling to unwind if the current stack frame is able to catch the exception. The personality is expected to use a specific set of tables located at the end of the function in order to fetch this information.
- If the stack frame can catch the exception, the personality will be called a second time with a different `actions` argument (cleanup phase).

Comment: Link is dead, could you post the title of it?

Comment: Updated the answer with the updated link: https://monkeywritescode.blogspot.com/p/c-exceptions-under-hood.html